# iOS in app purchase trial period test

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to get trial period from receipt?
I found interesting flag **is_trial_period** in receipt but, this field is not described in document.

May be you know other way how to get trial period from auto-renewable subscription?